# SQL Server : columns leaving blank spaces in it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with a database hosted by Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

I made a table with some `varchar(length)` columns.

The problem is, when I insert anything in it, it leaves "blank spaces" in the end of the column, messing everything up.

So the columns practically looks like this =

```
some_value _________
```

(`__` = blanks)

Sometimes the blank spaces are even longer...

And I cannot delete them, cause even when deleting them, they get back in place.

What is it the issue?

Is the `varchar(length)` too high?

The fact is I cannot set it shorter, cause the value I'm going to insert in the table isn't fixed in length..

Any fix?

Comment: Are you sure that the data you are inserting doesn't have trailing spaces?

Comment: How are you inserting the data? This is not normal behaviour for SQL Server, so my guess is that the problem is in whatever query or software you're using to interface to it.

Comment: Are you **sure** those are of type `varchar` ? What you're describing is **exactly** what's happening with  `char(n)` columns - they're padded to the defined length with spaces - well documented and understood behavior.

Comment: damn it, you guys were right.. the field was setted as nchar(lenght). .. changing it to varchar(lenght) now works as intended. . sorry for stupid question, I worked all night long, that particular escaped me